# JSP null reference pointer exception

Tags: jsp, nullreferenceexception

Trying to display how many times the user has visited a page.

```
 Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("SessionID", "b2");

      Integer visitCount = (Integer)request.getAttribute("visitCount");
      visitCount++;
     session.setAttribute("vistCount", visitCount);
```

Comment: you are getting `"visitCount"` while you are setting `"vistCount"` !! it's not the same

Comment: @PacMan i doubt that is the case since setAttribute accept String as its first parameter,so it can be anything,my bet would be that getAtrribute("visitCount") is returning null.better put those code within try/catch bloack and see it.